# install.packages() can't access a custom CRAN using a self signed SSL cert

Tags: r, ssl, cran

I've built a custom, on-prem, CRAN repo that needs to be served over HTTPS.

For reasons I wont bore you with, I'm using a self signed certificate generated with openssl.

The repo has been built and works fine over plain-old HTTP, but if I try to use HTTPS, i get the following error:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://server/cran/src/contrib:
 cannot open URL 'https://server/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I can access the URL with `curl -k` from the command line, but I can't figure out how to make it work with R.

I either need to tell R to blindly accept any certs, or somehow tell it about this cert/key.

the full command used to generate the cert was...

```
openssl -req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /path/to/file.key -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out /path/to/file.crt
```

I'm working on a RedHat Linux client at the moment, but it'll need to be accessible from Windows clients shortly too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parameterize `download.file()` via `options()`, and that should help with `install.packages()` as it uses `download.file().

In short, for as long as you can make it work with `curl` or `wget` you can farm the transaction out to them.

From `help(download.file)`:

> method: Method to be used for downloading files.  Current download
>             methods are ‘"internal"’, ‘"wininet"’ (Windows only)
>             ‘"libcurl"’, ‘"wget"’ and ‘"curl"’, and there is a value
>             ‘"auto"’: see ‘Details’ and ‘Note’.

There is a lot more on that page.  It should get you covered.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Ended up setting the environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE in Renviron and everything's better now.